# org.eclipse.microprofile @ConfigProperty does not work using openJDK13

Tags: apache-tomee, microprofile

We just switched from oracle jdk 10 to openJDK 13.
When we now try to start our tomee with

> set JAVA_OPTS=-Dconfigfilepath="path/to/config.xml"

we get the following exception:

> javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [java.lang.String] is not found with the qualifiers
>   Qualifiers: [@org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty(name="configfilepath", defaultValue="org.eclipse.microprofile.config.configproperty.unconfigureddvalue")]
>   for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  configPath, Bean Owner : [Configuration, WebBeansType:MANAGED, Name:null, API Types:[de.test.Configuration,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]

It works if we use the ConfigProvider directly. I hope someone can help with this problem.